# add "EXPIRE" tag in header while serving content

Tags: php, http-headers

does adding "EXPIRE" tag in header forces the browser to cache the content till the time expired ?
How to do so while serving an static image/css/js in PHP ?

Comment: Browsers already cache static content automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use header and gmdate functions:

```
// Actualy date in GTM 0
header('Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time())); 

// Las modify date (now, for example)
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time())); 

// The expire time (one hour in the future) <-- sorry my english!!!
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600));
```

Always make sure to send headers before sending data, ex:

```
// GOOD!
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600));
echo "content";

// BAD!
echo "some content";
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600));
```

If you need generate the content before send header, you can use a ob functions:

```
ob_start();

echo "content";
echo "more content";


header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600));
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: but how to server image using this method ? It's also heard to serve js/css i think using this way

Comment: perhaps ob_end_flush show be before header()  in the last example with ob functions. Otherwise I see no point in using of ob functions

Answer (score 0):

For static content use web server config. For apache it's .htaccess, for iis it's web.config.